# Hide domain name from subdomain name

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, web-hosting, nameserver, website

Lets have a domain test.com and the domain has various sub-domains for e.g support.test.com, contact.test.com, meta.test.com .

I want that when site visitor goes to meta.com, he should be directed to meta.test.com and the address bar should display meta.com. Also I want to do the same for all other sub-domains.

Can I do this? If yes, then how?

Note:- Using web hosting service and no web-server(software) at my end.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I do this?

Sure you can. You use a reverse proxy. The user stays on meta.com and the proxy pulls the content from meta.test.com

> Note:- Using web hosting service and no web-server(software) at my end.

Yeah. And that is the problem - unprofessional, no requirements solutions to bypas standard behavior = no go.

With these requirements:

Have meta.com use a frame element in HTML to pull the content from meta.test.com - as the top page shows the page loaded (from test.com) meta.gest.com will never show up. Unless some HTML demands to be the top page etc.

Comment: can you elaborate about framing element in HTML

Comment: No. This is (a) not a administrative question and (b) this site explicitly demands you know the basics of the technology you deal with. Tons of web tutorials out on the internet. Hire an administrator or web guy.